# Conformal Group when p+q>3

Tags: differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, conformal-geometry, conformal-field-theory

I am reading Martin Schottenloher's A Mathematical Introduction to Conformal Field Theory. On page 15, edition 2, or page 13 edition 1, he writes that for the case conformal killing factor is $0$, which implies

$$ X_{\mu , \nu} + X_{\nu , \mu} = 0.$$

This he claims implies

$$ X^{\mu}_{,\nu} = 0.$$

I do not understand how he reached this claim.

Then further he writes that this implies

$$ X^{\mu}(q) = c^\mu + w^{\mu}_{\nu} q^{\nu}. $$

Which does not make sense at all, as for the above form of $ X^{\mu}(q)$

$$ X^{\mu}_{,\nu} = w^{\mu}_{\nu}.$$

Comment: The equation $X^\mu_{,\nu}=0$ is a typo. What is meant that the equation $X_{\mu,\nu}+X_{\nu,\mu}=0$ actually implies that all _second_ derivatives are $0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the derivative of $X_{\mu,\nu}+X_{\nu,\mu}=0$ by $\alpha$ to get the relation:
$$X_{\mu,\nu\alpha} = -X_{\nu,\mu\alpha}$$
This means that for the second derivatives of a Killing field you can swap a component with a derivative and obtain a minus sign. Since the derivatives commute you can see:
$$X_{\mu,\nu\alpha} = - X_{\nu,\mu\alpha} = - X_{\nu,\alpha\mu}= X_{\alpha,\nu\mu}= X_{\alpha,\mu\nu} = -X_{\mu,\alpha\nu}=-X_{\mu,\nu\alpha}$$
and hence $X_{\mu,\nu\alpha}=0$ for any $\mu,\nu,\alpha$.